# Error when using wait() and fork() in c++

Tags: c++, c, fork, wait

I'm trying to use `wait()` and `fork()` in my c++ code. but I get the following error in the compilation phase

```
../test/my_test.cpp: In member function 'void MYClass::myMethod()':
../test/my_test.cpp:98: error: no matching function for call to 'wait::wait(int*)'
/data/backfire/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib/gcc/i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.1.2/../../../../i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc/sys-include/bits/waitstatus.h:68: note: candidates are: wait::wait()
/data/backfire/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib/gcc/i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.1.2/../../../../i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc/sys-include/bits/waitstatus.h:68: note:                 wait::wait(const wait&)
```

Code:

```
void MYClass::myMethod()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
       printf("error fork\n");
       return;
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* cild*/
        ......
    }
    /*parent*/
    while (wait(&status) != pid);
}
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error indicates that it was trying to create an object of a type called `wait`, converting from a pointer, rather than (as expected) trying to call a function called `wait`.

The problem is that you haven't included the header that declares the `wait` function. However, there is a type called `wait` defined in another header so, without the function declaration, the compiler assumes you mean that.

Solution, from the manpage for `wait(2)`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Comment: I m using c++ library and I checked the source of this library and that's right I find that it define wait() method in one of theses classes. how to avoid this problem? I m not able to modify the shared lbrary

Comment: @MOHAMED: Does it work if you use `::wait` instead of `wait` in your code, as I suggested in the answer? If not, then your library must be dumping names in the global namespace, and the only sensible solution is to throw it away and use something less evil.

Comment: using ::wait do not avoid the problem. does using `extern "c" { wait() }` could solve the problem ?

Comment: @MOHAMED: Actually, I think your code should work as long as the function has been declared. Are you including the correct headers, `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/wait.h>`?

Comment: it works when I add `<sys/wait.h>`. Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a constructor is being expected... Try

```
 while (::wait(&status) != pid);
```

Use the scope-operator to call the `wait`-function.
If this doesn't help, you have a name-clash and need to create a distinct namespace for your class.

```
namespace mywait{

  class MyClass {

  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with "bash.d".
if you have written the "waitstatus.h" yourself and you want to use the same, you need to wrap it inside a namespace.

If not, may be you want to try including sys/wait.h instead of waitstatus.h